# Why doesn't dismissWithClickedButtonIndex ever call clickedButtonAtIndex?

Tags: uitextfield, uialertview, iphone

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html

I'm using that code to get my iPhone app to display an alertView with an included UITextField and matching CANCEL and OK buttons.

The user can enter text, hit CANCEL or OK... and I see the text the user entered... using my code inside the clickedButtonAtIndex method.

It all works except for 1 thing:  Instead of OK, the user might hit DONE on the keyboard. 
I'm using dismissWithClickedButtonIndex to simulate an OK click... but then clickedButtonAtIndex never gets called.

Shouldn't dismissWithClickedButtonIndex also call clickedButtonAtIndex?

I'm trying to get clickedButtonAtIndex to get called if CANCEL, or OK, or even DONE is hit.

Answer (score 37):

Since this is an old question you've probably figured it out by now, but I was incredibly frustrated with this and couldn't find any help from Google, so for anyone who comes across this in the future: when you call `dismissWithClickedbuttonIndex`, the method that gets called is `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex`, not `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex`. It behaves exactly the same way, and I can't figure out why they'd be two separate methods for what seems to be the same action, but there it is.

Comment: Thank you for these lines, weird delegation pattern, dismissWithClickedButton should AT LEAST call both delegator methods one to deal with the button clicks and the other to deal with closing the alert. Confusing, redundant unnecessary complexity

Answer (score 2):

`clickedButtonAtIndex` is called when user actually clicks the button. Clicking the button  may or may not dismiss the alert. the standard OK/Cancel buttons have the effect of dismissing the alert on click. If a click translates to dismiss or a `dismissWithClickedbuttonIndex` method is called, then did `DismissWithButtonIndex` is called.

Comment: Indeed, but it makes no sense from a delegation pattern point of view. what this means is alertViewClickedButtonAtIndex is called SOMETIMES a button is pressed and not ALWAYS as the delegating method suggests. Whether it closes the alert or not which is a whole other issue, now that's the responsibility of didDismissWithButtonClicked:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I fully understand your question, but here is my try:

Firstly, you need to remove the `if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])` from the example. This should work for the OK and CANCEL buttons.

To recognize the DONE key of the keyboard, use `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` of the `UITextFieldDelegate`. Here you could call `[textField resignFirstResponder]` to dismiss the keyboard.

Also, what to you do in `clickedButtonAtIndex`? Couldn't you create your own method and the call it when you need it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with UIAlertView(Blocks) categoty
[UIAlertView-Blocks](https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UIAlertView-Blocks)

My solution:UIAlertView(Blocks) -> MYAlertView : UIAlertView

Sometimes method:`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` called. Sometimes it didn't call.

So... I tried to find solution in many sources. Then I'he created subclass of UIAlertView with absolutely same code. And my problem was solved. In fact it is little bit more difficult to use. But no more this intrusive bugs.