# Calling UIAlertView clickedbutton at index programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am trying to call UIAlertView's delegate method programmatically. Here is the code:

```
if([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]) {
        // Manually invoke the alert view button handler
        [(id <UIAlertViewDelegate>)vc alertView:nil
                           clickedButtonAtIndex:0];
    }
```

It works fine on iOS5.0 but is not working on iOS6.0 and comments or suggestions are most welcomed :)

Here is the complete method for detail:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *vc = [[[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
    // Settin The Initial Text
    [vc setInitialText:status];
    [vc setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {

            NSLog(@"Tweeted Sucessfully");
            }
    }];
    if([delegate isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]){
        [(UIViewController *)delegate presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
      //alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:
    if([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]) {
        // Manually invoke the alert view button handler
        [(id <UIAlertViewDelegate>)vc alertView:nil
                           clickedButtonAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in you code just give the alertview with your alertview obect name like bellow..

```
[(id <UIAlertViewDelegate>)vc alertView:yourAlertView
                           clickedButtonAtIndex:0];
```

otherwise Just try with this bellow code..

```
   id<UIAlertViewDelegate> delegate = yourAlertView.delegate;
    yourAlertView.delegate = nil;
    [delegate alertView:yourAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex:0];
```

see this link for some other option about it..

[why-doesnt-dismisswithclickedbuttonindex-ever-call-clickedbuttonatindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472854/why-doesnt-dismisswithclickedbuttonindex-ever-call-clickedbuttonatindex)

Comment: Actully I am trying to tap the "Settings" button on TWTComposeViewController's alertView.. i do not know whats the name of its alertview

Comment: hey see this link may you get some idea from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626821/app-would-like-access-to-twitter-accounts-alert-is-not-shown-in-ios-6 i hope its help you..

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to directly call delegate methods. `UIAlertView` has a method called `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`. If you call that, the `UIAlertViewDelegate` methods `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:` and
`alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` will be called, assuming your delegate is set correctly.

Comment: How can i get the name of TWTweetComposeViewController's alertView

Answer (score 1):

You can use this delegate this will work for you..

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no such differences regarding implementation of Alert view in iOS 6. You can complete your task easily by using this delegate method - :

```
(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

try this and after that let us know what kind of warning you get in  console...

Comment: I am using this to dismiss the TWTComposeViewController's AlertView and its not being dismissed, Tried the alertView: didDismissWithButtonIndex.

Answer (score 0):

TWTeetComposeViewController deprecated in IOS6. Please try with DETweet instead. :) Works fine on iOS 6 too. :)